# cocos2d: is the child of a child of a batch node handled by the batch node?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Badly worded question maybe... If I add a sprite as a child of a batch node, and then add another sprite as a child of the first sprite, will that sprite receive the same benefit of the batch node?  Or do you have to add it directly to the batch node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.1, the answer is yes. Make certain that the grand-child of the batch node has the same texture as that which was used for the batch node.

Comment: no need to make it certain because it'll be an error if it's not using the same texture ;)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D NSAsserts suck. Next game will be a turn-based self shooter called "The arcane BatchNode"